# Acomodar contenido en un PDF para imprimir con CSS

Tags: html, css3

estoy maquetando una impresion en pdf con html y css. El problema que tengo es que necesito que el footer me quede siempre abajo de la página pero que no se repita en cada una de ellas.

Implemente flexbox para el body poniéndole una altura mínima del 100% y al footer un margin-top: auto; para que se empuje hacia abajo siempre. Esto en situación de página web funciona perfectamente... ahora el problema se da cuando genero el pdf y en la imagen abajo se muestra que de igual manera el footer (lo que esta abajo de "observaciones") queda siempre pegado al resto.

Posibles causas que tengo en cuenta:

- Siento que podría ser que no me esté tomando el 100% de altura en el body??.. pero en el @media print{} esta declarado.
- No me está tomando el margin-top:auto; del footer en el pdf??.. aunque se lo coloco en el @media print{} y no lo toma.

Código:
El html véanlo simplemente como un body con un main y un footer dentro... dentro de estos dos últimos está el contenido (una tabla en cada uno) asique en teoría solo debo ubicar a estos dos.

El css es:

```css
<style type="text/css" media="all">
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      .exportProfileContent {
        font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px 40px;
      }

      .greenbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 48px;
        background-color: #7ed956;
      }

      .greenbar--top {
        border-bottom: solid 4px #007e34;
      }

      .greenbar--bottom {
        border-top: solid 4px #007e34;
      }

      h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: end;
        font-size: 48px;
        letter-spacing: 8px;
      }

      h2,
      h3 {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      h3 {
        text-align: end;
      }

      table,
      .main__table,
      .item_45,
      .footer__table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .main__table thead tr td,
      .main__table .logo {
        width: 240px;
        margin: 24px 0;
        padding: 0 16px;
      }

      .main__table .name,
      .main__table .email {
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .main__table .ticket,
      .main__table .date,
      .totals__table .total-title {
        text-align: end;
      }

      .observations {
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        margin: 40px;
      }

      .item_45 {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
      }

      .item_45 thead {
        background-color: #7ed956;
      }

      .item_45 thead tr th:first-child,
      .item_45 tr td:first-child {
        text-align: start;
        padding-left: 16px;
      }

      .item_45 thead tr th:first-child {
        width: 70%;
        background-color: #007e34;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .item_45 thead tr th:nth-child(3n-1) {
        width: 15%;
      }

      .item_45 th,
      .item_45 td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
      }

      .item_45 tr td,
      .totals__table p {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .item_45 tr td:last-child {
        background-color: #dfdfdf;
      }

      .totals__table tr td {
        padding-bottom: 24px;
      }

      footer {
        margin-top: auto;
      }

      .footer__table {
        margin: 48px 0 24px;
      }

      .footer__table tr td {
        padding: 0 16px;
        border-top: solid 2px #007e34;
      }

      .footer__table tr td:last-child {
        text-align: end;
      }

      @media print {
        body {
          min-height: 100%;
          font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif !important;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .pagebreak {
          break-inside: auto;
        } /* page-break-after works, as well */

      }
    </style>
```

[image: Imagen descriptiva de la impresión]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no tienes especificado el alto del contenedor, imagino que es el `main`, y por eso el `margin-top: auto;` no está teniendo ningún efecto.

Cuando aplicas `height: 100%;` el contenedor aplica el alto del padre, que en este caso no existe, porque lo aplicas al body.

La solución sería mover la declaración `display: flex;` y `flex-direction: column;`  del `body` al `main` y aplicar el alto total `height: 100vh;` o `height: 11in;`. Algo así:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <header>Header</header>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola! Tengo algo parecido, pero mi problema esta en que necesito que el contenedor este al final de la pagina, al estilo de position fixed, no logro colocar el elemento. Tengo la misma estructura en los estilos pero nose como manejar este caso